# How to switch elastic version on Docker

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I have elastic version `7.1.1`
I want to use version `6.3.2`

I need to start elastic using this command

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 5601:5601 nshou/elasticsearch-kibana
```

I've downloaded version 6.3.2 by this command

```
docker pull docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
```

Now when I run

```
docker run -d -p 9200:9200 -p 5601:5601 nshou/elasticsearch-kibana
```

it still uses `7.1.1`. How do I switch that to `6.3.2`?

**EDIT**
This is how my `docker images` looks like
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there are 2 images of `elasticsearch-kibana` in your local.One for 7.1.1 and other for 6.3.2. You should provide the version as well with image name while running docker.

```
docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2
```

Better to run `docker images` command once to check the tag for the respective image and use that to run docker.

Comment: When I do so it throws: "Unable to find image 'nshou...; locally . In images i can see 6.3.2 though

Comment: I've updated the post with images. I want to run through nshou/ealstic, so that it has both kibana and ES in one container

Comment: You should use docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.3.2 in docker run

Comment: Is it possible to use nshou/elasticsearch instead?

Comment: Their is only 1 version of nshou/elastivsearch image i.e latest. This image might contain elastic search version 7.1.1 when it was created.How did you create this image?
Else you need to create another image with kibana ans ES(6.3.2)

Comment: I've used this https://hub.docker.com/r/nshou/elasticsearch-kibana/

Comment: use docker pull nshou/elasticsearch-kibana:<tagName> to pull the specific image.When you don't provide tag name it pulls latest
nshou/elasticsearch-kibana:kibana6 this image will have ES and kibana 6.5.4. There is no image with ES version 6.3.2 under this hub directory

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202599/discussion-between-ratish-bansal-and-eric-klaus).